# What is this sticky surface underneath the trunk carpet?

Tags: suzuki, trunk

While inspecting a Suzuki Swift 2008, I noticed a weird sticky surface beside the spare tire well.

[image: Under the trunk mat]

Does anybody know what this is?

Comment: Is the other side sticky in a similar way?  ie, left of shot and left of the spare tyre well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The grey section in the photo is sound deadening material.  It is used to stop the metal panels vibrating.  It was glues onto the panel when the car was made.  It is also possible to buy self adhesive sheets of this to as more sound deadening.

Why it is sticky to the touch could be on purpose to hold that carpet down, or maybe it has just become sticky as it has become old.

Answer (score 2):

Either it is there to stop the carpet or soundproofing “walking” during use or somebody split something.

My money is on the former.